# awk find/print paragraph containing multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

Request:

Extract blocks of text that contain 2 or more search terms, something akin to [ AND ] logical operator in [ awk ].

Preferably run as awk in bash/zsh function (but also ok with standalone awk script), accepting input/parameter in regex style:

[ A|B|C ] = return blocks that contain either 'A' or 'B' or 'C'

[ A&B&C ] = return blocks that contain ALL 'A' and 'B' and 'C'

Context:
Blocks are separated by at least 5 new lines.

Extra:
Highlight search matches.

### Input

Given [ veganPackage.txt ] input file:

```
1. Fruits 
Apple
Banana
Honey
   - tasty combo but too many sugars
   - Low prep time
   - bad for teeth, cavity warning 




2. Drinks
Apple Juice
   - served cold and ripe

Add Kiwi
   - peel first

Banana Smoothie
   - tastes good
   - fast power up



3. Veggies
Frillice
Cucumber 
Tomato
```

---

### Want

| Input | Blocks to print | Colorize words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple|Banana | Fruits, Drinks | Apple, Banana |
| Apple|Banana|Frillice | Fruits, Drinks, Veggies | Apple, Banana, Frillice |
| Apple&Banana | Fruits, Drinks | Apple, Banana |
| Apple&Tomato | *nothing* | *nothing* |
| Kiwi&Banana | Drinks | Kiwi, Banana (only in Drinks) |

---

### Tried

#### Bash function

Named as [ searchBlock ]

```
searchBlock ()
{
...

awk \
  -v RS='\n{4}' \
  -v ORS='\n***\n***\n' \
  -v color=$colorOut \
  -v colorReset=$colorReset \
  -v search=$(echo "$searchTerm" | perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)&+/\/&&\//g and s/^/\//g and s/(.)(?=$)/\1\//g') searchTerm \
  -v searchAND=$(echo $searchTerm | perl -pe 's/&+/|/g') '$0~search{gsub(searchAND,color"&"colorReset);print}' $file |
  vim - -c "/$searchTerm" \
        -c ':AnsiEsc' \
        -c 'highlight ColorReverse gui=reverse cterm=reverse' \
        -c ":match ColorReverse /$searchTerm/"
}
```

Example Call as:
 `searchBlock -s 'Apple|Banana' veganPackage.txt`

### Rationale:

- if OR pattern as [ | ] in input,  do regular match
- if AND pattern as [ & ] in input, preserve [ | ] for colorizing, but change to [ && ] for pattern marching
- feed operand as part of parameter

### Bottleneck

1. If I manually feed `'/Apple/&&/Kiwi/{gsub(/(Apple|Kiwi)/,color"&"colorReset);print}' veganPackage.txt`, then output as expected:

```
\*\*\*
\*\*\*

2. Drinks

Apple Juice

   - served cold and ripe

Add Kiwi

   - peel first

Banana Smoothie

   - tastes good

   - fast power 
up

\*\*\*
\*\*\*
```

However, using `'$0 ~ search{gsub(searchAND,color"&"colorReset);print}`, [ AND ] pattern #fails (nothing is printed)

(not what I filtered/searched), highlight/coloring is correct though)

- `$0 ~ search` = for every block that contains pattern in awk [ search ] variable,
- `{gsub(searchAND,color"&"colorReset);print}` = print global substitution of searched text surrounded by ANSI Escape sequences

  - [ & ] is double-quoted as regex-specific syntax (NOT to be confused with [ && ] in AND-pattern match for awk))

It seems that `$0 ~ /Apple/&&Kiwi/` does NOT collab with me.

#### Tests

| Input | Code fragment | Result | Expect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple|Kiwi | `$0~search` | Fruits, Drinks | Fruits, Drinks |
| Apple&Kiwi | `$0~search` | *nothing* | Drinks |
| Apple|Kiwi | `search` | *entire file* | Drinks, Fruits |
| Apple&Kiwi | `search` | *entire file* | Drinks |
| Apple&&Kiwi | `search` | *entire file* | Drinks |
| /Apple/&&/Kiwi/ | `$0~search` | *nothing* | Drinks |
| Apple&&Kiwi | `$0~search` | *nothing* | Drinks |

Answer (score 2):

Focusing solely on `awk` and the use of dynamically generated regexes ...

Assumptions:

- you're able (in `bash`) to parse/reformat the various inputs into formats that are acceptable to `awk`

General approach:

- pass the `gsub()` regex in as a `-v variable=value` clause
- pass the search regex by piecing together strings to build (on-the-fly) the `awk` script
- we'll simplify the `gsub()` code to bracket the matches with a pair of underscores (`__`); OP can incorporate the color codes later

A simple data set for demonstration purposes:

```
$ cat simple.dat
line_1 - Apple
line_2 - Banana
line_3 - Kiwi Cherry Apple
line_4 - Apple Kiwi
line_5 - Kiwi
```

We'll use a `bash/for` loop to test a few different search regexs (the `gsub()` regex is the same for all 3 search regexes):

```
for search_regex in "/Apple/ && /Kiwi/" "/Apple|Kiwi/" "/Apple/ || /Kiwi/"
do
    printf "\n########## search : ${search}\n\n"

    awk -v gsub_regex="Apple|Kiwi" ' 
    BEGIN { filler=ignore }
    '"${search_regex}"' { gsub(gsub_regex,"__&__") }
    1
    END   { filler=ignore }
    ' sample.dat

done
```

**NOTE:** here's where I'm assuming OP can parse the various input formats into one of these formats for the two regex variables

Where:

- 1st part of `awk` script: `'BEGIN { filler=ignore } '`
- 2nd part of `awk` script: `"${search_regex}"` ; must be wrapped in double quotes
- 3rd part of `awk` script: `' { gsub(gsub_regex,"__&__") } 1; END { filler=ignore }'`
- there must not be any white space between the single quotes (1st/3rd parts) and the double quotes (2nd part) (ie, `'"${search_regex}"'`)

Taking for a test drive:

```
########## search : /Apple/ && /Kiwi/

line_1 - Apple
line_2 - Banana
line_3 - __Kiwi__ Cherry __Apple__
line_4 - __Apple__ __Kiwi__
line_5 - Kiwi

########## search : /Apple|Kiwi/

line_1 - __Apple__
line_2 - Banana
line_3 - __Kiwi__ Cherry __Apple__
line_4 - __Apple__ __Kiwi__
line_5 - __Kiwi__

########## search : /Apple/ || /Kiwi/

line_1 - __Apple__
line_2 - Banana
line_3 - __Kiwi__ Cherry __Apple__
line_4 - __Apple__ __Kiwi__
line_5 - __Kiwi__
```